# cant get Serialize HtmlHelper to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

i looked at : http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx

but when i post the page the model(ie person) returns as null?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([DeserializeAttribute]Person person, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
```

//this line has an error:
            TryUpdateModel(person, formCollection.ToValueProvider());

```
        return View(person);

    }


    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home"))
   {%>
<%=Html.Serialize("person", Model)%>
<%=Html.EditorForModel() %>
<button type="submit">
    go</button>
<%
    }%>

 [Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string suburb { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to bind the person from the request using the following:

```
TryUpdateModel(person, formCollection.ToValueProvider());
```

when you explicitly know that there is no such thing in the request? This line invokes the model binder and tries to read it from the request values. But in your form you only have a single hidden field. So your action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([DeserializeAttribute]Person person)
{
    // Do something with the person object that's passed as
    // action argument
    return View(person);
}
```

Also your scenario looks strange. You have a view which seems to be strongly typed to this `Person` object in which you are using `Html.EditorForModel` meaning that you are offering the user possibility to edit those values. If you serialize the model you will get old values in your controller action. This attribute is only useful when you want to persist some model between multiple requests but there is no corresponding input fields in the form so that the default model binder can reconstruct the instance in the POST actions.

Comment: @user603007, did you remove the `[DeserializeAttribute]` attribute from your action parameter?